# Knockout not binding updated value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a knockout model and binding it with my asp.net mvc view . Here is my model

```
function SearchListingViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.selectedBedRooms = ko.observableArray([]);
self.minPrice = ko.observable();
 self.search = function () {   
    var data = {
        Status: self.selectedStatus(),
        MinPrice: self.minPrice(),
        MaxPrice: self.maxPrice(),
        BedRooms: self.selectedBedRooms(),
        PageNumber: 0,
        PageSize : self.pageSize()
    };

    $.post("/listing/searchlistings", data)
    .done(function (json) {
        self.Listings(json.listings);
        json = json || {};
        if (json.success) {
            //Inserting commas in all listing's price --- Start

            $(json.listings).each(function () {
                var selfthis = this;
                console.log(selfthis.Price);

                selfthis.Price = "45,352,2"; // You can see i am hardcoding price here 


                console.log(selfthis.Price);
            });

            //Inserting commas in all listing's price --- End

            self.Listings(json.listings);
            self.pages(json.pages);
            self.pageCount(json.pageCount);
            if (self.Listings().length <= 0) {
                Alert.Information('No results found!');
            }
        } else if (json.errors) {
            Alert.Error(json.errors[0]);
        }
    });

}
```

**My View**

```
<div data-bind="foreach : Listings"> 
    <span data-bind="text:Price"></span>
</div>
```

**Json Data**

```
 {Price:555555, Commission:0, MarketingDescription:null, ListingStatusId:1, PlaceId:32, Place:null,…}
```

When it renders it show this on screen

```
 555555 43434343 5454545454 4563665 343
```

Instead of

```
45,352,2 45,352,2 45,352,2 45,352,2 45,352,2
```

What the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this a typo    selfthis.Price = "45,352,2";?/

Comment: @iBlue no , i am hard coding it by myself

Comment: can u post json data here

Comment: @iBlue see I updated my question with json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh , it was a problem by my side ,

```
.done(function (json) {
    self.Listings(json.listings); // here i am setting listings into observable array before editing this was the problem 
    json = json || {};
```

after removing this line it work accurately .

Answer (score 0):

As far as i think i believe that what ur accessing is the Price of Listings which is set from the json data, which is printing in the console.

Try changing

```
selfthis.Price = "45,352,2";
```

to
    `self.Listings.Price = "45,352,2";`